# Cocoa Touch - Text Boxes Question

Tags: cocoa-touch

I have a chalk board image and I want it to be like it your writing on the chalk board so the textbox would have to invisible but still functioning....

Any idea how I could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the text box's backgroundColor property to [UIColor clearColor]